# in pnpm monorepo condition，someone workspace pakcage being dependend on mutiple workspace package in the way of workspace

Tags: dependency-management, monorepo, yarn-workspaces, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

for example:

1.packageB depended on packageA by workspace

2.add packageC and packgeC also depended on packgeA by workspace

3.when develop packageC, i modify the packageA

4.now, packageB was influenced, because packgeA was changed when develop packgeCand

how to solute this problem, i wish to manage subPackages only by the way of worksapce

Comment: it sounds natural. what's the problem?